# I want to change the format of the last row of a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am retrieving a table from MySQL database and displaying the records in an HTML table. But the last row of the table is displaying Total values. And I want to make it bold. Just the last row values of the result set. How to do so?

```html
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'system';
$db_pwd = 'system';
$database = 'mydb';
$table = 'records';
if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");
if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");
// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td style='font-weight:bold'>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: use tfoot for last row and add some css to it

Comment: I don't see a table closing tag `</table>`

Comment: You can use the sql `SUM` function to count all values

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this at the end (or at the top, doesn't really matter) :

```
<style>
  table tr:last-child{
    font-weight: 900;
  }
</style>
```